# How to quickly replicate a 6-byte unsigned integer into a memory region?

Tags: c++, c, memory

I need to replicate a 6-byte integer value into a memory region, starting with its beginning and as quickly as possible. If such an operation is supported in hardware, I'd like to use it (I'm on x64 processors now, compiler is GCC 4.6.3).

The `memset` doesn't suit the job, because it can replicate bytes only. The `std::fill` isn't good either, because I even can't define an iterator, jumping between 6 byte-width positions in the memory region.

So, I'd like to have a function:

```
void myMemset(void* ptr, uint64_t value, uint8_t width, size_t num)
```

This looks like `memset`, but there is an additional argument `width` to define how much *bytes* from the `value` to replicate. If something like that could be expressed in C++, that would be even better.

I already know about obvious `myMemset` implementation, which would call the `memcpy` in loop with last argument (bytes to copy) equal to the `width`. Also I know, that I can define a temporary memory region with size `6 * 8 = 48` bytes, fill it up with 6-byte integers and then `memcpy` it to the destination area.

Can we do better?

Comment: I think that your last approach is the best we can get.  Fill a small region of *n* bytes manually, then `memcpy` it once to double, then `memcpy` the doubled region of 2 *n* bytes to get 4 *n* bytes and so forth.  Finally, `memcpy` the last portion (which, in general, will not be a power of two) to complete the task.  You'll only have a logarithmic number of function calls.

Comment: I don't understand what `memset()` and `std:fill` can do for you, since you say you want to replicate a number, not clear it. `memcpy(&destination,&source,6)` is the best, what do you think could be improved?

Comment: You can expand on your last idea and go even larger than 48 bytes. For that matter you can make it recursive; fill the first 6 bytes manually, then use memcpy to expand it to 12 bytes, expand to 24 bytes, 48 bytes, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't mean to use a separete region.  Use the beginning of `ptr` (in the OP's function parameter list) and continue until it is filled.

Comment: @5gon12eder - the iterative memory-size-to-copy enlargement looks promising, thanks!

Comment: @MikeNakis - the replication is so basic, I hoped it has been covered already in standard lib or somewhere else

Comment: Is there something to be got from treating the 48-bit integer as either three `int16_t`, or a `int32_t` and a `int16_t`?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're using 6-byte integers. If it's to conserve space, I'd recommend you reconsider. The speedup by using naturally-aligned 8-byte integers will probably outweigh the space savings, even if you don't use SSE instructions on your data. But you haven't really told us what you're doing.

Comment: The most C++ way would be an iterator and `std::copy`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a521244b39e3567  Why do you need something faster?

Comment: Would be nice to tell us what worked best in the end...

Comment: @YvesDaoust - thank you for the hard-to-find info about low level copy instructions. I think I'll try more C/C++ way at first and then, if performance is not good, I'll probably switch to assembler inlining

Comment: @MooingDuck - could you please write a bit more explanations about your code?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - why not? 4-byte integers can't index the object universe I'm working with, and 8-byte integers are kind of overkill. I can tolerate a little overhead during each number read/write access but I want to *initialize* the whole array as fast as possible

Comment: @HEKTO: memcpy is tuned for maximum performance, little chance to beat it with standard C++ code.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, but a 6 byte memcpy in a loop is probably not optimal.

Comment: @HEKTO: I thought it was pretty self-explanatory, but here it is with comments I guess: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a18705321d4e402.  I made an iterator that repeats a pattern, and then "copied" from that iterator to the target buffer.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I didn't recommend such a solution. Any code that will use an explicit loop has great chances to do worse, and code that amounts to an implicit loop has great chances to be implemented on top of memcpy. So use memcpy and do it in a smart way, unless you think this is old fashioned.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I recommend such code because it is _readable_, since the original poster has given no indication whatsoever that any such code is a performance bottleneck.  However, since neither I nor anyone else has actually tested it, I put it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck: the request is clearly "as quickly as possible".

Comment: One more thing - there's a good chance that the timings will be dominated by the access to RAM if it isn't already in the cache, and the code itself will matter hardly at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write 8 bytes at a time.

Being on a 64-bit machine, certainly the generated code can operate well with 8-byte writes.  After dealing with some set-up issues, in a tight loop, write 8-bytes per write about `num` times.  Assumptions apply - see code.

```
// assume little endian
void myMemset(void* ptr, uint64_t value, uint8_t width, size_t num) {
  assert(width > 0 && width <= 8);

  uint64_t *ptr64 = (uint64_t *) ptr;
  // # to stop early to prevent writing past array end
  static const unsigned stop_early[8 + 1] = { 0, 8, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
  size_t se = stop_early[width];
  if (num > se) {
    num -= se;

    // assume no bus-fault with 64-bit write @ `ptr64, ptr64+1, ... ptr64+7`
    while (num > 0) { // tight loop
      num--;
      *ptr64 = value;
      ptr64 = (uint64_t *) ((char *) ptr64 + width);
    }

    ptr = ptr64;
    num = se;
  }
  // Cope with last few writes
  while (num-- > 0) {
    memcpy(ptr, &value, width);
    ptr = (char *) ptr + width;
  }
}
```

Further optimization includes writing 2 blocks at a time `width  == 3 or 4`, 4 blocks at a time when `width == 2` and 8 blocks at a time `width == 1`.

Comment: Are you saying that this code is faster than the code in your previous answer (with multibyte copying)?

Comment: Also i'm afraid it will overwrite previosly written bytes

Comment: @HEKTO Faster depends of the compiler, allowable compiler settings, platform and data set.  (you have provide 2 of those 4) This is just another candidate for the horse race.  Yes is does overwrite previously written bytes, that is not the issue as the bytes overwritten need to be overwritten.  The issues is does it get the correct job done fastest?  Why care if ti over-writes some bytes?  What is nice here is the tight loop does not need to read the source data repeatedly.  Once source is in `value`, likely kept in a register for optimized code.

Comment: Probably your idea (for `width = 6`) is to copy two lowest bytes of the `value` to its highest bytes - then the overwriting won't be destructive, but I don't see that in your code

Comment: @HEKTO (Assuming a little endian machine and `char * cptr = ptr`) With a `value = 0x1122334455667788; width = 6;` and large `num`, the first `*ptr64 = value;` results in `cptr[0] = 0x88; cptr[1] = 0x77; cptr[2] = 0x66; ... cptr[7] = 0x11;` After the next `*ptr64 = value;` results in `cptr[6] = 0x88; cptr[7] = 0x77; cptr[8] = 0x66; ... cptr[13] = 0x11;` and so on.

Comment: Got it - it'll overwrite unused highest bytes

Answer (score 6):

Something along [@Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) comment:

Copy 6 bytes, then 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, etc.

```
void memcpy6(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n /* number of 6 byte blocks */) {
  if (n-- == 0) {
    return;
  }
  memcpy(dest, src, 6);
  size_t width = 1;
  while (n >= width) {
    memcpy(&((char *) dest)[width * 6], dest, width * 6);
    n -= width;
    width <<= 1; // double w
  }
  if (n > 0) {
    memcpy(&((char *) dest)[width * 6], dest, n * 6);
  }
}
```

Optimization: scale `n` and `width` by 6.

[Edit]
Corrected destination [@SchighSchagh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072468/schighschagh)
Added cast `(char *)`

Comment: This got me thinking: dividing the amount of memory to fill by 6 gives you a bit set indicating 'what to do'. However, a head cold is wreaking havoc with my math skills and so I cannot deduce what 'what' is supposed to be. (Doubling the copy size? Incrementing the copy-to pointer? Both?)

Comment: @Jongware  Yes, double the width of the copy per each iteration, copying the initial portion of the destination as the source to the the next ever increasing offset offset in the destination.

Comment: It takes a bit of extra processing inside the supposedly tight inner loop, but on the other hand, your current way stops at 64 if it has to fill 127 sextuples, and reverts to 'dumb' copying after that.

Comment: `memcpy()` is inlined by most compilers, so there are many chances that using it alone will yield best results, especially if the compiler is in a position of knowing the alignment of the source and destination. So, the clever logic presented in this answer may in fact yield slower results. I am not saying that this will necessarily happen, I am saying that there are many chances that it will happen. So, be sure to benchmark plain repeated `memcpy()` vs. this algorithm.

Comment: shouldn't it be `dest` rather than `src` in the `while(...) { memcpy(...) ...}`?

Comment: @Mike: but the *number* of `memcpy` calls (inlined or not) decreases significantly. Surely that's got to have some effect.

Comment: @Jongware  For 127 blocks, first `memcpy()` of 1 block, then loop copies, 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 blocks.  Last `memcpy()` copies 31 blocks.

Comment: @Mike Nakis I would suspect repeated calls to `memcpy(,,6)` would be faster than this when `n` is small for the reasons you cited.  But with large `n`, any overhead with a true function call is diminished.  Yet profiling is best - we do know OP's typical sizes of `n`.

Comment: @Jongware If the compiler optimizes an entire call to `memcpy()` with this: `mov [edi], eax`; `mov [edi+4], dx`; `add edi, 6`; then the best thing you can do is just let exactly this code execute as many times as necessary. That's because '6' is a constant.  Trying to outsmart the compiler may cause the compiler to actually have to invoke a non-inlined `memcpy()`.  This is very likely if N is not a constant.

Comment: A true function call to `memcpy()` is actually quite expensive.  The majority of the code in `memcpy()` deals with memory alignment issues. Not to mention that a true call to `memcpy()` will always read in order to write; if you can avoid the reading and only write the contents of registers, then you have a clear winner.

Comment: Some ISAs have an instruction that allows for, after the usual preliminaries, a memcpy-like copy directly taking a source, destination and length.  The advantage to that with large `n`, is that the instruction bus is quiet, allowing for data read and write.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Yes, thank-you - lost it in an edit - now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Determine the most efficient write size that the CPU supports; then find the smallest number that can be evenly divided by both 6 and that write size and call that "block size".

Now split the memory region up into blocks of that size. Each block will be identical and all writes will be correctly aligned (assuming the memory region itself is correctly aligned).

For example, if the most efficient write size that the CPU supports is 4 bytes (e.g. ancient 80486) then the "size of block" would be 12 bytes. You'd set 3 general purpose registers and do 3 stores per block.

For another example, if the most efficient write size that the CPU supports is 16 bytes (e.g. SSE) then the "size of block" would be 48 bytes. You'd set 3 SSE registers and do 3 stores per block.

Also, I'd recommend rounding the size of the memory region up to ensure it is a multiple of the block size (with some "not strictly necessary" padding). A few unnecessary writes are less expensive than code to fill a "partial block".

The second most efficient method might be to use a memory copy (but *not* `memcpy()` or `memmove()`). In this case you'd write the initial 6 bytes (or 12 bytes or 48 bytes or whatever), then copy from (e.g.) `&area[0]` to `&area[6]` (working from lowest to highest) until you reach the end. For this `memmove()` will not work because it will notice the area is overlapping and work from highest to lowest instead; and `memcpy()` will not work because it assumes the source and destination do not overlap; so you'd have to create your own memory copy to suit. The main problem with this is that you double the number of memory accesses - "reading and writing" is slower than "writing alone".

Answer (score 3):

If your `Num` is large enough, you can try using the AVX vector instructions that will handle 32 bytes at a time `(_mm256_load_si256`/`_mm256_store_si256` or their unaligned variants).

As 32 is not a multiple of 6, you will have to first replicate the 6 bytes pattern 16 times using short memcpy's or 32/64 bits moves.

```
ABCDEF
ABCDEF|ABCDEF
ABCD EFAB CDEF|ABCD EFAB CDEF
ABCDEFAB CDEFABCD EFABCDEF|ABCDEFAB CDEFABCD EFABCDE
ABCDEFABCDEFABCD EFABCDEFABCDEFAB CDEFABCDEFABCDEF|ABCDEFABCDEFABCD EFABCDEFABCDEFAB CDEFABCDEFABCDEF
```

You will also finish with a short memcpy.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `__movsq` intrinsic (x64 only; in assembly, `rep movsq`) that will move 8 bytes at a time, with a suitable repetition factor, and setting the destination address 6 bytes after the source. Check that overlapping addresses are handled smartly.